# LF Flowcharting Software that Integrates with a Drawing Tablet

Tags: open-source, drawing, tablet, flowchart, design

I'm used to diagramming flowcharts by hand. The extra speed and hand-eye coordination is IMO a better experience. Workflow is faster and memory is improved.

Is there flowchart software that integrates with a drawing tablet?

Ideally free, opensource, running on macOS.

The software should be able to achieve figure recognition based on what is drawn on the tablet, then convert it into an editable flowchart on the desktop.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome! For what is the "LF" in the title an abbreviation?  BTW, I agree with your reasons for wanting this.  I have had the same experience.